# Android Dialog for user input

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am new to Droid and am trying something which should be so simple that it's driving me insane.

I have a FragmentActivity:

public class ScanView extends FragmentActivity

... and on here I have a button which opens a dialog/alert window to allow the user to enter a value. Then I want that value back in the calling code. Does anyone have an example which (a) compiles and (b) actually works? So many examples online, but none of which work...

The closest example I found involves making an AlertDialog, but it won't compile at (ViewGroup)getView() below:

View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_bc,  (ViewGroup)getView(), false);

Any ideas??

Comment: "Then I want that value back in the calling code" -- showing a dialog is an asynchronous operation. You can *use* the result of the dialog, but you will do so via a callback when the the dialog is accepted, which does not fit with my definition of "...back in the calling code". In terms of dialog code that works, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Dialogs/DialogFragment) worked the last time that I tried it.

Comment: Thanks - the callback part was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android dev guide provides an example for that here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

When you handle the positive/negative button events in the dialog, you could save whatever value you want to pass back in a instance var and then pass the event (along w/ the instance of the dialog) to your FragmentActivity.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that page before but the example didn't work straight off. It doesn't actually show you how to get the value back (only what was clicked). However, I worked it out once I read the page in full.